# Как адаптировать unserialize после смены модификаторов свойств объекта?

Tags: php, ооп, сериализация

У меня в базе хранятся сохранённые данные в которых есть объект у которого при serialize() были свойства private, но в какой-то момент объект потребовалось наследовать и переопределять и свойства стали protected, в итоге при Unserialize() объект приходит пустой. Каким образом можно адаптировать старые данные к новым модификатором объекта?

Есть объект:

```
class MyClass{
 private $id;
}
```

Его сериализуем функцией serialize() свойство `$id=123`.
Потом объект меняет модификатор для свойства

```
class MyClass{
   protected $id;

   public function __wakeup()
   {
     if (is_string($this->id)) {
        $this->id = (int) $this->id
     }
   }
}
```

и при десиарилизации функцией unserialize() у нас объект **MyClass** со свойством `$id` пустой.
так же есть сеттеры и геттеры для данного свойства и на `__wakeup` идёт обработка свойства `$id`

Comment: Реализуйте функцию `__wakeup`

Comment: Это да, но как мне адаптировать именно модификаторы, у меня в объекта на ` __wakeup ` в `$this` например 2 свойства:
`id => null` и `AppBundle\MyEntity id => 123`

Comment: добавьте [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Провел серию экспериментов. Ответ на вопрос зависит от версии PHP.

## Минимальный пример

Файл для сериализации `ser_priv.php`:

```
class MyClass{
  private $id;
  public function __construct($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
  }
}

$o = new MyClass(123);
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/data', serialize($o));
```

Файл для десериализации `unser.php`:

```
class MyClass {
  // Заменили на protected
  protected $id;
  public function __construct($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
  }

  public function test() {
    $prop = new ReflectionProperty('MyClass', 'id');
    printf("prop is protected: %d\n", $prop->isProtected());
    printf("prop has value: %d\n", $this->id);
  }
}


$data = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/data');
$o = unserialize($data);
$o->test();
```

[На github](https://github.com/dbfun/serialize-private)

## Результаты

**PHP 7.3.0RC4**: protected свойство устанавливается верно, тем же значением, что и было.

**PHP 5.6.33**: protected свойство НЕ устанавливается верным образом после `unserialize`.

Если сделать `var_dump($o);`, то выведется

```
object(MyClass)#1 (2) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["id":"MyClass":private]=>
  int(123)
}
```

`var_export($o);`:

```
MyClass::__set_state(array(
   'id' => NULL,
   'id' => 123,
))
```

"Достать" 123 приличным способом не получилось. Неприличный способ типа `var_export` и парсинг результата не рассматривал, но это - тоже вариант.

Теперь сериализуем один и тот же объект, но в первом случае будет `private`, во втором `protected`. Посмотрим бинарник, что получилось:

```
$ xxd data_priv 
0000000: 4f3a 373a 224d 7943 6c61 7373 223a 313a  O:7:"MyClass":1:
0000010: 7b73 3a31 313a 2200 4d79 436c 6173 7300  {s:11:".MyClass.
0000020: 6964 223b 693a 3132 333b 7d              id";i:123;}
$ xxd data_prot 
0000000: 4f3a 373a 224d 7943 6c61 7373 223a 313a  O:7:"MyClass":1:
0000010: 7b73 3a35 3a22 002a 0069 6422 3b69 3a31  {s:5:".*.id";i:1
0000020: 3233 3b7d                                23;}
```

Получается, что `private` хранится как ".MyClass.id", а `protected` как ".*.id", только вместо точек бинарные нули. Ну и длина строки разная (`s:11` и `s:5`).

Идея - подменять `private` на `protected`. Что-то универсальное делать не хочется, может кто-то заморочится. Вот минимальный вариант по переделыванию `id`.

Файл `unser_php56.php`:

```
class MyClass {
  // свойство с измененной областью видимости
  protected $id;
}

$data = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/data_priv');

$data = bin2hex($data);
// Заменяем определение свойства
$data = str_replace('31313a22004d79436c617373', '353a22002a', $data);

$data = hex2bin($data);

$o = unserialize($data);
var_dump($o);
```

Результат:

```
object(MyClass)#1 (1) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  int(123)
}
```

Comment: Да, действительно на php выше 7.1 работает нормально, но на версиях ниже, придётся заниматься реплейсами) 
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=74586